# displayLink - compiler keep fix me forever

Tags: swift

I am trying this :

```
    displayLink.add(to: .current,  forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
```

then he correct me to this :

```
    displayLink.add(to: .current,  forMode: .RunLoop.Mode.default)
```

then he gives an error :

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

I can't figure out how to write this line.

code before :

```
 let displayLink = CADisplayLink(
            target: self, selector: #selector(displayLinkDidFire)
        )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `forMode:` parameter should just be `.default`.

```
displayLink.add(to: .current, forMode: .default)
```

or if you wanted to fully qualify it:

```
displayLink.add(to: .current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
```